# SQL Server, case statement across multiple tables, vlookup

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, vlookup

I have  a table 1 which is as follows

```
ID1    ID2         Name                     Balance
10232   22      Building America            7000
10233   22     Long term                   3400
10234   25         Capital                  2300
```

Table 2 is as follows

```
ID1    note     Balance
10233    2         5000
10234   1        3500
```

The code has to first go table to table 1,  and check if the ID1 exists in table 2 , if it does not exist then select Balance by Table 1. If it goes exist in table 2 and finds that note is 1 then it still picks up the balance from Table 1 and if it finds that note in table 2 is greater than 1, then it checks if the ID1 has multiple ID2 and if it does have multiple ID2, it checks if there are other ID1 which is not the same and then adds the balance from Table 2 and the other ID found in table 1.
So for ID1 =10233, the code goes to table 2 and finds that note is 2. The corresponding ID2 of  10233 is 22. It then checks if there are any ID1 are there which contain the same ID2. The two ID1s which have same ID2 are 10232 and 10233. It then adds the Balance of 10233 from Table 2 and then adds the Balance of 10232 from Table 1. So the balance for the this ID is 5000+7000= 12,000.

For ID 10234  it is 2300 as it finds that note is 1 and picks up only from table 1.

Am having a lot of problem with building logic around this and am stuck with just a bunch of case statement. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: Geeee... thats one hell of the logic. Find the guy responsible for this and do something bad to him.

Answer (score 1):

Any time your logic becomes this convoluted, it is a red flag that your database design might not be up to snuff and refactoring should be considered.  Nevertheless, this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b19fa/8) shows a query that seems to work.

Edit:  Your description didn't make it clear whether 'Building America' should be excluded since it gets lumped in with long-term.  If so, look at [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b19fa/11) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started: do a left join:

```
SELECT <...>
FROM dbo.table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.table2 t2
ON t1.ID1 = t2.ID2
```

then you can access all the columns of the two tables in one case statement. If no fitting row in table2 exists, those columns will be set to NULL.

Details about the different joins you can find here:http://sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/